# Математические операции с датами на языке PHP

Tags: php, математика

Здравствуйте!
Есть задача:

Существует сайт, где можно выбрать и вырастить кристаллы.
К примеру выбрали какой-то кристалл. Нажали кнопку "вырастить"
В базу записалось значение - время начала роста.
У кристаллов есть время роста (10 дней например).
Чтобы камень вырос быстрее, можно покупать проценты роста.
Если покупаем 1 процент роста - время старта переносится на определенное время назад. 
Как можно найти это время и как найти процент готовности который будет после обновлении времени старта.

Возможно есть другой подход, чтобы найти на сколько, в процентах, вырос кристалл после каждого обновления страницы и сколько времени осталось рости кристаллу.

Мне помогли найти формулу решения:

```
{время_старта} - ( (10*24*60) * 0.01) = новое время старта
(10*24*60) / ({сейчас} - {новое время старта}) * 100 = текущий процент.
```

Пытаюсь выполнить операции с датами:

```
$новое_время_старта= date(
   'Y-m-d h:i:s',
   strtotime($исходное_значение_времени_старта) - ( (10*24*60) * 0.01));

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$текущий_процент = (10*24*60) / date(
                                'Y-m-d h:i:s',
                                (strtotime($date) - strtotime($новое_время_старта)) * 100);
```

Если новое значение времени старта вычисляется, как мне кажется, верно, то с процентами совсем результат не верный.

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.

#

Кажется сделал все как предложил Sergiks, но результат не тот..

Что знаем сейчас:
 $days - срок роста кристалла в сутках

И так, выбрали кристалл и нажали кнопку вырастить.
:

```
$time = time();
$start = new DateTime('@' . $time);
$finish = new DateTime('@' . ($start + 86400 * $days));

$tsStart = date_timestamp_get($start);
$tsFinish = date_timestamp_get($finish);
```

$tsStart и $tsFinish - записали в базу (в виде int).

Дальше, мы можем увидеть текущий процент готовности при каждом обновлении страницы. Считаем так:

```
$now = time();
$progress = (time() - $tsStart) / ($tsFinish - $tsStart);
if( $progress >= 1) {
    // вырос, забирайте
} else {
    // готовность 100 * $progress процентов
}
```

При покупки  процентов ($procent) время финиша пересчитываем вот так:

```
$finish = new DateTime('@' . ($tsStart + (1 - $procent / 100) * 86400 * $days));
```

И записываем в базу:

```
$tsFinish = date_timestamp_get($finish);
```

И процент готовности вычисляется также:

```
$now = time();
$progress = (time() - $tsStart) / ($tsFinish - $tsStart);
if( $progress >= 1) {
    // вырос, забирайте
} else {
    // готовность 100 * $progress процентов
}
```

Но результат всегда разный, бывают даже отрицательные значения.
Скажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1):

В PHP время чаще всего считается в секундах, так поступим и мы.

Известно: время начала роста `$start` в секундах с начала Unix эпохи, получено функцией `time()`; и продолжительность роста в сутках `$days`, которые переведём в секунды `86400 * $days` и получим объект [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php) даты финиша:

```
$finish = new DateTime('@' . ($start + 86400 * $days));
```

Когда купили «ускоритель» на 1%, старт тот же, а путь от старта к финишу сократился, стал `0.99 * 86400 * $days`. И новый финиш считается так:

```
$finish = new DateTime('@' . ($start + 0.99 * 86400 * $days));
```

В БД вы сохраняете `$start` и актуальное значение `$finish`, вернее, их целые значение unix timestamp:

```
$tsStart = $start->getTimestamp();
$tsFinish = $finish->getTimestamp();
```

При очередном визите, вы их извлекаете из БД, знаете, сколько времени сейчас, и прогресс считаете простой пропорцией:

```
$now = time();
$progress = ($now - $tsStart) / ($tsFinish - $tsStart); // 0..1
if( $progress >= 1) {
    // вырос, забирайте
} else {
    // готовность 100 * $progress процентов
}
```

Выше все вычисления были в секундах, и, по большому счёту, нет необходимости связываться с объектами [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php), но они здорово помогают в ситуациях, когда, напр., надо к дате прибавить две недели, возиться с временными зонами, вычислять разницу между двумя датами.

Comment: Вариант, когда $finish не сохраняется в бд, а рассчитывается перед выводом не рассматривали? (сохраняем только факты покупки "ускорителя"). В этом случае можно было бы исправлять ошибки без потери информации..

Comment: @VladimirGamalian не рассматривал. Во-первых, о каких ошибках идёт речь? Ошибок не должно быть в принципе. Во-вторых, в рабочем проекте недавно похожую ситуацию решили именно таким образом: хоть данные можно вычислить, храним актуальные значения, т.к. гораздо чаще требуется чтение результата, чем запись или перепроверка.

Comment: Например неправильно формулу ввели, или решили пересмотреть коэффициенты. Или ещё хуже какие-то дополнительные ввели модификаторы, которые хитрым образом сплетаются с уже имеющимися.. А то, что чаще читается чем пишется, это уже меморизацией/кешированием обычно решается. Т.е. в бд сохраняется информация, которая уже не изменится - факт покупки. А далее уже можно вертеть ею как угодно. В противном случае может теряться какая информация, которая вдруг может пригодиться. В подобных играх, кстати, непрерывный процесс - выравнивание баланса.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим время роста 10 дней, это 24 часа * 10 = 240 часов

значит 1 процент роста это 2,4 часа

допустим стартовое время 10.08.2016 13-40

допустим купили 2 процента это 4,8 часа

конечно время 20.08.2016 13-40

отнимем от него процент роста и получим время